# Electric utility boundary lines in US

Tags: data-request, usa, geospatial, energy

I'm looking for shapefiles or other spatial definitions for electric utility service areas in the United States. Does this exist in a single place anywhere?

Answer (score 6):

The US Energy Information Administration has a few geographic resources (like the [US Energy Mapping System](http://www.eia.gov/state/maps.cfm) and the [State Energy Data System](http://www.eia.gov/state/seds/) but there's no sign of a collection of electric utility service areas.

On a state-by-state basis, there are a variety of resources available. This might provide a roadmap for motivated parties to request shapefiles and assemble the dataset. I'm going to make this answer a 'community wiki' in case other people want to flesh it out with more states or hunt further for GIS files on states where PDFs were easier to find..

- [Arkansas](http://gis.arkansas.gov/?product=electric-utility-service-territories-polygon) (map, shp, gdb)
- [California](http://www.energy.ca.gov/maps/serviceareas/Electric_Utility_Service_Areas.html) (map, shp)
- [Connecticut](http://www.ct.gov/deep/cwp/view.asp?a=2698&q=322898&deepNav_GID=1707%20#Utility) (gdb, shp) Utility Infrastructure and Pipelines
- [Illinois](http://www.ilenergyassn.org/electric-utilities-illinois-map/) (unofficial PDF map)
- [Indiana](http://maps.indiana.edu/previewMaps/Infrastructure/Energy_Electric_Service_Territories.html) (map, shp)
- [Iowa](http://www.iowadot.gov/maps/msp/electrical/StatewideElectricalBoundaryMap.pdf) (pdf map)
- [Kentucky](https://psc.ky.gov/Home/Maps)
- [Massachusetts](http://www.mass.gov/anf/research-and-tech/it-serv-and-support/application-serv/office-of-geographic-information-massgis/datalayers/pubutil.html) (map, shp; town-level detail only)
- [Minnesota](http://www.mngeo.state.mn.us/chouse/utilities.html#service) (.shp, .gdb, .kmz, OGC GeoPackage)
- [New Hampshire](https://www.psnh.com/downloads/NH%20Electrical%20Utilities%20Map.pdf?id=4294968510&dl=t) (pdf map)
- [North Carolina](http://ncelectriccooperatives.com/downloads/territoryMap.pdf) (pdf map of co-ops)
- [Vermont](http://geodata.vermont.gov/datasets/vt-electric-utility-franchise-areas) (.shp)
- [Wisconsin](https://psc.wi.gov/utilityinfo/maps/documents/largeElectricMap.pdf) (pdf map)

US (National/Federal)
 - [Bureau of Transportation Statistics Geospatial Information](http://www.rita.dot.gov/bts/sites/rita.dot.gov.bts/files/subject_areas/geographic_information_services/index.html)

Canada
[Atlas of Canada Energy GIS](http://atlas.nrcan.gc.ca/site/english/maps/energy.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, state-by-state isn't really helpful for me. I have to imagine someone has compiled boundary lines by utility for the entire US. I'll leave this question open until we have a more solid answer. In the meantime, I'll keep looking into this.

Comment: @AmosBudde I've worked with electric service territories across many states, and I'm 99% sure there is no publicly available dataset with national coverage. Otherwise, the commercial datasets from Platts ([one](http://www.platts.com/IM.Platts.Content/ProductsServices/Products/gismetadata/iou_terr.pdf), [two](http://www.platts.com/IM.Platts.Content/ProductsServices/Products/gismetadata/non_ious.pdf)) wouldn't cost $300+ per state.

Comment: Thanks @dmahr for your thoughts here. I'll investigate the commercial datasets you referenced.

Comment: This answer is out of date. A public dataset does exit (see my answer below).

Answer (score 2):

A website by the Dept of Energy called NEPAnode has this, disclaimer it is a project I manage. You can downloaded these vector datasets in a number of formats including shapefile:

http://nepanode.anl.gov/layers/geonode%3Aferc_regions

http://nepanode.anl.gov/layers/geonode%3Anerc_regions

http://nepanode.anl.gov/layers/geonode%3Afpma_reg

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, these are boundaries of regulatory commissions and not service areas. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: These are the best public datasets on electric transmission boundaries... You will not find utility level service areas for the entire US. I second the thread above

Answer (score 2):

I was able to obtain TVA's service territory from TVA, but otherwise I have not found anything in addition to the resources listed above.

(Note I would have added this as a comment to the existing thread but I need a higher reputation I guess.)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like the Homeland Infrastructure Foundation - Level Data (HIFLD) Retail Electric Service Territories shapefiles?

> This feature class/shapefile represents electric power retail service territories. These are areas serviced by electric power utilities responsible for the retail sale of electric power to local customers, whether residential, industrial, or commercial.

Found [here](https://hifld-geoplatform.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/electric-retail-service-territories).

Comment: seems to be the real thing -- would be great for other folks to give it a look and upvote this answer if they agree

Answer (score 1):

This is the source I use for electric utility service territories:

https://hifld-geoplatform.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/electric-retail-service-territories/data?orderBy=NAME&orderByAsc=false

It is through the US dept of Homeland Security. I can't promise that it is perfect, but this type of geographic info is hard to come by